# Accessing Gitlab Api with HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am trying to access my the API on my Gitlab server. It works with curl but not from my C# code.

```
curl --insecure https://gitlab.mycompany.de/dev/TestProjekt/milestones -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Private-Token: my_token"
```

```cs
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (obj, certificate, chain, errors) => (true);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri("https://gitlab.mycompany.de/dev/TestProjekt/milestones"));
req.Headers.Add("Private-Token", "my_token");
req.Accept = "application/json";
req.Method = "GET";
var res = req.GetResponse();
```

My C# code causes an WebException with the message "underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send" (i got german error message, but i am convinced that this is the correct translation)

In my opinion both requests should send the same data. I tried sending requests to http instead of https to see the packages in wireshark. Curl sends an additional header "user agent" and c# sends "Connection: Keep Alive". Adding a user agent to the C# request won't help either.

Does anyone have an idea what might be different?

Comment: Is `https://gitlab.mycompany.de` actually the server, or is that merely an example?

Comment: it is the server, but i am not allowed to post the name of the company here. "my_token" also is a replacement for the actual token.

Answer (score 0):

After Cleaning and Rebuilding everthing multiple times, I now get the expected answers.