# API Authentication and Use C# GitLab API

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, api, gitlab

I've never used an API and am making an application looking to make a call for the merge request for a specified branch and to get all discussion comments from that merge request. I'll be using the GitLAB API. According to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/ there are four ways to authenticate, but shouldn't each authentication be unique to each individual using my application (because everyone would have a different gitlab account with different accesses)?

Not sure how to use API's correctly with WPF c# but I will be trying to make use of https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#list-all-merge-request-notes

And then I guess for setting up the actual calls would you probably use

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (obj, certificate, chain, errors) => (true);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri("https://gitlab.mycompany.de/dev/TestProjekt/milestones"));
req.Headers.Add("Private-Token", "my_token");
req.Accept = "application/json";
req.Method = "GET";
var res = req.GetResponse();
```

Found at [Accessing Gitlab Api with HttpWebRequest in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731984/accessing-gitlab-api-with-httpwebrequest-in-c-sharp)

Comment: So what is your actual question?  Did you get an error? If so, post it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman First question is about authentication, since this is a method that the application uses, do I need to get an authentication token from each user? Unfortunately I do not have access to test today for New Years Eve but I've never used an API so just hoping to be steered in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the API. Usually you at least need a developer (application) code. How access to for instance orter accounets is regulaed varies.